# Selenium Java refresh element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am programming an automated bot that reads data from a site. It reads the data correctly but now i wanted to do it with an interval with Timers.
So i wrote a class extending TimerTask and it worked. I now have the problem that my program reads every time the same data even if it changed.

```
    messages =  Driver.findElements(By.className("messages")).get(0).findElements(By.className("message"));
    String message = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++){
        try{
            message = messages.get(i).findElements(By.className("text")).get(0).getAttribute("innerHTML");
            System.out.println(message);
        }catch(StaleElementReferenceException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

If I do this with JavaScript on that site I always get refreshed results but here in my java program it`s everytime the same.

Comment: Do you always want to get the first "messages" ?? Driver.findElements(By.className("messages")).get(0) Would you want to increment it ? how is your site structured ?

Comment: there is only one messages element but i have to search it with class so i make get(0)

Comment: Please post a screenshot of some sample data along with the text of the relevant HTML.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SASwBLMV

Comment: There aren't 947 lines of relevant HTML. You need to narrow it down to just the relevant parts and post it in the question. You will need to paste a screenshot of what this looks like. I'm not going to create an account on some random site on the internet to help with this and neither are most people.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/fe3acd6e6ccb14fe6c7c25e6404626aa

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7VVqFCpi -> Here is one sample message with the div messages surrounding it

Comment: i dont know where my fault is ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by simplifying your code. I would recommend you spend some time reading up on CSS Selectors. They are very powerful and fast. You can basically combine all three of your locators into one so that you only have to search once and you shouldn't end up with stale elements.

```
for (WebElement message : Driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".messages .message .text")))
{
    System.out.println(message.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
}
```

[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[SauceLabs: CSS Selectors Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

NOTE: if you only want the first element, there's no need to use `.findElements().get(0)`, just use `.findElement()`. Note the singular instead of the plural.

Comment: Nice info mate but i get still this repeating thing

Comment: Are you sure you are loading the right page? The one that is supposed to be up-to-date? If so it sounds like some kind of weird caching issue. This code should work... or you will have to do some more investigation and see what else you can find. Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: this site is named society and as i said with my javascript extension it worked but only with selenium in combination with phantomjs it doesnt work

Comment: What's the URL of the site? Please post the code that works and what the expected output is so we can compare.

Comment: the site is http://society.gg and my original javascript code of my extension is placed her: http://pastebin.com/wCgsAesD